# How to create a high quality wake-word solution for Android/ios app. Which technology stacks to try?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, training-data, voice-recognition, kaldi, keyword-spotting

I am trying using:

1. Tensor flow lite- unable to achieve desired accuracy & training sample size requirement seems to be very high.
   Q1) What's the minimum sample size required?
2. Kaldi - size send to be around 30MB, prohibitively high.
   Q2) What are the pros& cons of using Kaldi?

Also, I have tried using models & stacks from:

1. Porcupine
2. Spokestack
3. Sensory

Currently, I am evaluating Edge Impulse.
Q3) Can anyone guide me how to convert the .lite model to. tflite?

Q4) What am I missing??